# Проблемы с отображением recyclerView в диалоге после удаления элемента

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня в приложении есть диалог в котором отображается список прикрепленных к письму файлов. Список заполняется данными из массива в котором находятся элементы в формате json. Дальше я пытаюсь сделать удаление по свайпу. Если я правильно понял, то удалятся будет не только элемент из массива но и элемент из списка. Все вроде хорошо, но есть несколько проблем. При удалении элемента у меня в списке остается пустое место и список не обновляется. А после повторного вызова диалога со списком у меня вообще список ничем не заполняется хотя в логах показывает что массив не пустой. Вот как я вызываю диалог со списком прикрепленных файлов:

```
attachment.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (array.size() > 0) {
                    if (movieList.size() > 0) {
                        movieList.clear();
                        showDialog(SHOW_ATTACHED_FILES);
                        prepareList();
                    } else {
                        showDialog(SHOW_ATTACHED_FILES);
                        prepareList();
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, "NO attached files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

и вот построение диалога:

```
dialog = new Dialog(WriteResponseMess.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_attachment);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

final RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);

final AttachmentAdapter mAdapter = new AttachmentAdapter(movieList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
array.remove(i);
}
}
};

new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

вот функция которая заполняет список:

```
public void prepareList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(object.get("filename")));
            Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(object.get("data")));

            Integer data = object.get("data").toString().getBytes().length;
            movieList.add(new FileList(String.valueOf(object.get("filename")), String.valueOf(data)));
        }
    }
```

вот например нашел такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data) но после его внедрения в слушатель свайпа у меня приложение начало крашится по разным причинам. Не могу понять где и что я не так делаю. Надеюсь на вашу помощь и полезные советы.

### update

```
   @Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
array.remove(i); // удаляем запись из источника (как я понял)
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); // уведомляем адаптер об удалении
movieList.remove(position); // удаляем запись из коллекции адаптера ---- здесь ошибка 
}
}
```

код ошибки:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
```

Comment: Цикл-то зачем? Вы же хотите удалить один элемент а не все разом.

Comment: да но я так понял что индексы в списке не соответствуют индексам массива, или это не так? просто если цикл не вставлять то другая ошибка

Comment: Вы скопируйте мой код. У Вас в цикле удаляется одна позиция (`position`) и когда в списке остаётся меньше элементов чем `position` и выстреливает ошибка.

Comment: @woesss, я скопировал, цикл убрал, все сделал так как у вас, но все-равно ошибку кидает - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4` хотя все как у вас

Comment: Вы ввели меня в заблуждение именем параметра - это ж не позиция а направление свайпа. Обновил код.

Comment: @woesss, я поспешил в принятии вашего ответа, все работало вроде норм, но отображения прикрепленных файлов нету) странно честно говоря, скомпилировал проект выгрузил на эмулятор, в первом запуске все работало божественно, но вот при последующих запусках список прикрепленных файлов не отображался почему-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После удаления элемента наверное надо уведомить адаптер, чтобы он перерисовался: `mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`. Только непонятно что Вы делаете в `onSwiped`...
Может имелось ввиду это:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    array.remove(position); // удаляем запись из источника (как я понял)
    movieList.remove(position); // удаляем запись из коллекции адаптера
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); // уведомляем адаптер об удалении
}
```

**Update:** Если я правильно понял смысл Вашего кода, то так должно работать:

```
attachment.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (array.size() > 0) {
                    showDialog(SHOW_ATTACHED_FILES);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, "NO attached files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

---

```
final RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
prepareList();
final AttachmentAdapter mAdapter = new AttachmentAdapter(movieList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

---

```
public void prepareList() {
    movieList.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(object.get("filename")));
        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(object.get("data")));

        Integer data = object.get("data").toString().getBytes().length;
        movieList.add(new FileList(String.valueOf(object.get("filename")), String.valueOf(data)));
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает ваш метод, кидает fatal_exception  - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4` на строку `array.remove(position)`

Comment: А что за условие в `attachment.setOnLongClickListener`? Из-за него адаптер может отображать не только то что есть в `array` - отсюда и выход за пределы массива.

Comment: если этого условия не писать, то при каждом длительном нажатии у меня добавляется в список все элементы по новой, в итоге каждого элемента там по несколько штук может быть

Comment: Если Вам нужно показать только содержимое `array` - уберите условие `if (movieList.size() > 0)` и очищайте `movieList.clear()` безусловно. Хотя похоже, что нарушена последовательность действий и диалог показывает не актуальное содержимое.

Comment: да это решило часть проблем, но приложение крашится все-равно, закинул удаление элемента в цикл, но теперь обновление адаптера выбрасывает меня

Comment: обновил вопрос с вашим кодом, там я указал строку которая ошибку выбрасывает. У меня почему-то неправильно удаление работает, как бы я его не делал